# Scrape Alertmanager API

Tags: python, oauth, openshift, prometheus-alertmanager, okd

I have an Openshift 3.11 cluster with the default installation of Prometheus and Alertmanager.
I want to write a python script to scrape the Alertmanager API endpoint so that I can parse the data and pass that on to s third party monitoring tool for our ops team.
My problem is that to get to the API I need to authenticate against oauth. How can I do this within python?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is any different for alert manager compared with the Reddit API, but when I set up a bot for that, I had to first register it on their OAuth page, then I needed to use the codes that it gave me there, to request an access token with the rest of my user data (Login and password as well as what the application was called) Then I could use that authentication to contact the API endpoint.

Here is the function I made to request the access token from Reddit:

```
def AuthRequest():
    import requests
    import requests.auth
    import json

    client_auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('Application ID code', 'OAuth secret code')
    post_data = {"grant_type": "password", "username": "Your_Username", "password": "Your_Password"}
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Name_Of_Application"}
    response = requests.post("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token", auth=client_auth, data=post_data, headers=headers)

    return response.json()
```

And here is the code that contacts the endpoint and takes the data from it:

```
    import requests
    import requests.auth
    import json

    currentComments = []

    headers = {"Authorization": auth['token_type'] + " " + auth['access_token'], "User-Agent": "Your_Application_Name"}

    mentions = requests.get("https://oauth.reddit.com/message/unread.json", headers=headers).json()
```

Note here that 'auth' is simply the 'response' from the authentication token. I hope that helps, I don't really know how this differs with alertmanager as I've never really had to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for me.

I needed to create a service account

```
oc create serviceaccount <serviceaccount name> -n <your-namespace>
```

Then create a cluster role binding for it

```
oc create clusterrolebinding <name for your role> \
  --clusterrole=cluster-monitoring-view \
  --serviceaccount=<your-namespace>:<serviceaccount name>
```

Get a token from the SA and then use that in the curl

```
oc sa get-token <serviceaccount name> -n <your-namespace>
```